# What is good introductory literature on (meta)heuristics?

Tags: reference-request, heuristics, metaheuristics

What textbook/articles would you use to introduce heuristics and meta-heuristics to OR students? Assume they have already seen some OR (e.g., LP and MILP).

Answer (score 7):

This will be opinion based, but I personally like "Handbook of meta heuristics" edited by Michel Gendreau and Jean-Yves Potvin. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-1665-5

There is also "Metaheuristics for Business Analytics" if you are teaching business school students. https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319681177

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an introductory textbook, I think "[Metaheuristics: From Design to Implementation](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Metaheuristics%3A+From+Design+to+Implementation+-p-9780470278581)" by El-Ghazali Talbi is a very good option as it covers various design ideas and issues as well as different metaheuristics.

Answer (score 1):

An introduction to several algorithms can also be found in "Stochastic Local Search - Foundations and Applications" by Holger Hoos and Thomas Stützle. It contains an overview of the main methods, analyses, and some applications.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781558608726/stochastic-local-search